# Dummy Encoding using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, encoding, pyspark, dummy-variable

[image]

I am hoping to dummy encode my categorical variables to numerical variables like shown in the image below, using Pyspark syntax.

I read in data like this

```
data = sqlContext.read.csv("data.txt", sep = ";", header = "true")
```

In python I am able to encode my variables using the below code

```
data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns = ['Continent'])
```

However I am not sure how to do it in Pyspark.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
categ = df.select('Continent').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()
exprs = [F.when(F.col('Continent') == cat,1).otherwise(0)\
            .alias(str(cat)) for cat in categ]
df = df.select(exprs+df.columns)
```

Exclude df.columns if you do not want the original columns in your transformed dataframe.

Comment: Is there a faster solution?

Comment: it also uses alot of memory

Comment: This works well. High memory usage is normal I guess, if you have a lot of unique values in the column.