# Error occured when creating dummy variables-SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 59 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am getting an error using pyspark on Anaconda Python 3.6. The error message is
***SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 59 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times.***

This a full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-aa2b9549c767> in <module>()
      1 import pyspark.sql.functions as F
----> 2 categ = df.select('Event').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\xgboost\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
    812         """
    813         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 814             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    815         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    816 

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\xgboost\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\xgboost\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\xgboost\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 59 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 59.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 64, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 253, in main
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 248, in process
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 379, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 664, in load_stream
    yield self.loads(stream)
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 658, in loads
    s = stream.read(length)
  File "C:\Users\SadeDorasamy\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\xgboost\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1651)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1639)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1872)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1821)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1810)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 253, in main
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 248, in process
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 379, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 664, in load_stream
    yield self.loads(stream)
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 658, in loads
    s = stream.read(length)
  File "C:\Users\SadeD\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\xgboost\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithKeys_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

The error occurs in the code below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
categ = df.select('Event').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()
```

I am trying to create dummy variable for categorical data in events.

```
exprs = [F.when(F.col('Event') == cat,1).otherwise(0).alias(str(cat)) for cat in categ]
df = df.select(exprs+df.columns)
```

In addition to this, that code

```
categ = df.select('Event').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()
```

uses alot of memory and therefore take along time to run. The pyspark is running locally. What is causing this error? How can it be resolved or is there a optimal way to obtain the dummy variable that is less expensive?

Comment: What are you trying to do with flatMap()?

Comment: I found an example in link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528207/dummy-encoding-using-pyspark in order to create dummy variables. The example uses a flatMap.