# pyspark explode one-hot encoded vector to each column with proper name

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, one-hot-encoding

Applying one-hot encoding to multiple categorical column

```
X_cat = X.select(cat_cols)

str_indexer = [StringIndexer(inputCol=col, outputCol=col+"_si", handleInvalid="skip") for col in cat_cols]
ohe = [OneHotEncoder(inputCol=f"{col}_si", outputCol=f"{col}_ohe", dropLast=True) for col in cat_cols]
# ohe.setDropLast(False) # older version

pl = Pipeline(stages=str_indexer + ohe).fit(X_cat)
X_cat = pl.transform(X_cat)

si_cols = [col_nm for col_nm in X_cat.columns if col_nm.endswith("_si")]
ohe_cols = [col_nm for col_nm in X_cat.columns if col_nm.endswith("ohe")]
X_cat_ohe = X_cat.select(ohe_cols)
```

gives me

```
root
 |-- workclass_ohe: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- education_ohe: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- marital-status_ohe: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- occupation_ohe: vector (nullable = true)

+-------------+---------------+
|workclass_ohe|  education_ohe|
+-------------+---------------+
|(8,[4],[1.0])| (15,[2],[1.0])|
|(8,[1],[1.0])| (15,[2],[1.0])|
|(8,[0],[1.0])| (15,[0],[1.0])|
|(8,[0],[1.0])| (15,[5],[1.0])|
```

which is basically

```
    workclass_ohe                                   education_ohe
0   (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1   (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
2   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)    (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
3   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
4   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
```

I want to explode value in vector to new column with proper name.

desired output

```
 workclass_state-gov  workclass_selfemp  workclass_private  workclass_middle education_1   education_2  education_3
         0                   0                     0                1               0              0            1
         0                   1                     0                1               0              0            1
         1                   0                     0                0               1              0            0
        ...
```

From [pyspark - Convert sparse vector obtained after one hot encoding into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931269/pyspark-convert-sparse-vector-obtained-after-one-hot-encoding-into-columns)

I could add new columns however from `X_cat_ohe` I cannot figure out which value(ex: state-gov) corresponds to 0th vector, 1st vector and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Dummy Encoding using Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528207/dummy-encoding-using-pyspark) I can extend it to multiple columns.

```
for col_nm in cat_cols:
    category = X.select(col_nm).distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()
    category = [col_nm + "_" + ct for ct in category]
    exprs = [f.when(f.col(col_nm) == ct, 1).otherwise(0)\
              .alias(str(ct)) for ct in category]
    X = X.select(exprs+X.columns)
```